# Errors in sbt Scala project

Tags: macos, scala, sbt, osx-mavericks

Created a sample Scala project structure (on my OS X Mavericks based computer) as follows:

Inside sample_project dir:

```
src
    main
      java
      scala
        Hello.scala
      resources
    test
      java
      scala
      resources
 build.sbt
```

Hello.scala:

```
object Hello {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = println("Hello!")
}
```

build.sbt:

```
name := "hello"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"
```

Placed the build.properties under sample_project/project:

```
sbt.version=0.13.5
```

When I try to run it using the "sbt" command inside the root folder:

```
/sample_project $ sbt
Getting org.scala-tools.sbt sbt_2.8.1 0.13.5 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.8.1;0.13.5

    ==== local: tried

      .ivy2/local/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt_2.8.1/0.13.5/ivys/ivy.xml

      -- artifact org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.8.1;0.13.5!sbt_2.8.1.jar:

      .ivy2/local/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt_2.8.1/0.13.5/jars/sbt_2.8.1.jar

    ==== Maven2 Local: tried

      file://.m2/repository/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.8.1/0.13.5/sbt_2.8.1-0.13.5.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.8.1;0.13.5!sbt_2.8.1.jar:

      file://.m2/repository/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.8.1/0.13.5/sbt_2.8.1-0.13.5.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt_2.8.1/0.13.5/ivys/ivy.xml

      -- artifact org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.8.1;0.13.5!sbt_2.8.1.jar:

      http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt_2.8.1/0.13.5/jars/sbt_2.8.1.jar

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.8.1/0.13.5/sbt_2.8.1-0.13.5.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.8.1;0.13.5!sbt_2.8.1.jar:

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.8.1/0.13.5/sbt_2.8.1-0.13.5.jar

    ==== Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository: tried

      http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.8.1/0.13.5/sbt_2.8.1-0.13.5.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.8.1;0.13.5!sbt_2.8.1.jar:

      http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.8.1/0.13.5/sbt_2.8.1-0.13.5.jar

    ==== Scala-Tools Maven2 Snapshots Repository: tried

      http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.8.1/0.13.5/sbt_2.8.1-0.13.5.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.8.1;0.13.5!sbt_2.8.1.jar:

      http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.8.1/0.13.5/sbt_2.8.1-0.13.5.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.8.1;0.13.5: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.8.1;0.13.5: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see sample_project/project/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.5
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an sbt version mismatch. Create a `project` directory under `sample_project` and inside it create a file called `build.properties` with the following contents:

```
sbt.version=0.13.5
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an old *launcher* version of `sbt`, perhaps even too old to cope with the new `0.13.5`.

Try to [update](http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html) your launcher to the latest version. On MacOS, the easiest way is to use the [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) package manager. If not already done, install it with:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

then, install `sbt`:

```
$ brew install sbt
```